# How to export a HTML form as QR Code?

Tags: javascript, qr-code

I have done a fair amount of googling and researching, but couldn't find a solid guide or something similar which explains following:

> My plan is to generate a form (via my own form creator, just a little
>   JavaScript browser app) and then generate a QR code from it. Later on,
>   I want to create a native mobile phone app which reads the QR code and
>   "imports" the form on the screen where I can fill it out.

But, I have no idea either I can code this on my own or I need a QR service for this (which I don't prefer).

**I would hope to get some guidelines, steps to approach this problem.**

I am familiar with JavaScript (also Node) and other languages. Everything I can code my own is fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "export a HTML form as a QR code"?

Comment: QRCode is nothing else as a information container, in your case, the code can link to a web server that render the http request, another approach can be to develop your own parser and develop this form native in the app... is up to you..

Comment: Thanks! So when I create the form, the QR Code has all the information of the website included? So I want to bring the html form to a mobile phone by reading the QR Code. Where can I read how the QR code is generated and how this all works? I am totally clueless so far.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Well that's what I am thinking. Can you lead me please to a direction? What can a QR Code include? Just a link? I want to create a form, and wrap it up in a "QR Code" so I can scan the code on my mobile phone and have the form in my native app. What would be a approach?

Comment: I've used the QR generator from this repository: https://github.com/kazuhikoarase/qrcode-generator It has code for many languages, including javascript

Comment: Probably you need to encode just the URL where that phone can get a new (empty) instance of the form. You don't want to encode all html.

Answer (score -1):

http://officetricks.com/generate-qr-code-google-chart-api/

Export a HTML form as QR Code

Please check it

Its working